# How to optimise the sum for each db column. Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, optimization

I'm looking for a better way to retrieve data from scores table. I need to add the the sum for each columns and add it to a json object.

The goal is to render a json object like this...

```
   data = {
      labels: ['M', 'Tu', 'W', 'Th', 'F', 'Sa', 'Su'],
      series: [
        [15, 2, 4, 35, 0, 20, 40] // The sum each day from the column NO_OF_ATTEMPTS
      ]
    }
```

...From this database table named "scores"...

```
ID   | NO_OF_SUCCEEDED | NO_OF_FAILED | NO_OF_ATTEMPTS | UPDATED_AT
---- | --------------- | ------------ | -------------- | -------------------
86   | 19              | 3            | 22             | 2016-09-07 22:25:07
87   | 18              | 2            | 20             | 2016-09-07 22:25:56
88   | 31              | 10           | 41             | 2016-12-01 18:20:10
89   | 14              | 0            | 14             | 2016-09-07 22:21:45
90   | 16              | 0            | 16             | 2016-09-07 22:24:09
91   | 17              | 3            | 20             | 2016-09-07 22:43:45
```

Atm I wrote something like this...

```
data = {
          labels: [
            24.hours.ago.strftime("%A"),
            Time.now.strftime("%A")
          ],
          series: [
            [
              current_user.scores.where(updated_at: 
                  48.hours.ago..24.hours.ago).sum(:no_of_attempts),
              current_user.scores.where(updated_at: 
                  24.hours.ago..Time.now).sum(:no_of_attempts)
            ]
          ]
        }
```

This code goes for each day to get the sum of NO_OF_ATTEMPTS. 7 days is 7 requests to the database. Later I also want to add an json array with NO_OF_FAILED and NO_OF_SUCCEEDED. That means 7 request for 3 columns = 21 request.

***QUESTION: Is it possible to do this in one single request or at least fewer.***

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use group by and sum for this please find the sample from which you can achieve it in minimal query

current_user.scores.group('DATE(scores.updated_at)').pluck("SUM("scores.no_of_attempts").where(updated_at: 168.hours.ago..Time.now)")

not tested but hopefully work